# Travel guides stores in Rome

Tags: shopping, rome, guides, guidebooks

Could you tell me please where can I find a store in Rome to buy a travel guide such as Lonely Planet?

I hope you there's one near Termini station because that's the only place I know :)

Appreciate it

Comment: There is a bookstore when you leave Termini towards la Piazza del Cinquecento on the front side of the station, should be easy to find.

Comment: Do you know the name of the store please ?

Comment: Also do you think I can find one in the airport?

Comment: The mainstream brick-and-mortar bookstore names are: FNAC, Feltrinelli, Mondadori, Borri. Look for these on google maps.

Comment: @JoErNanO: There are no FNACs in Rome anymore; and Borri is not exactly a “mainstream name”, but it has indeed a good, large bookshop inside Termini station. I'd add Arion for the chain bookshops, and lots of independent ones.

Comment: @DaG  thanks for your comment, that was two months ago, now I'm already back, Miss Rome so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a surprisingly large bookstore, named [Borri Books](http://www.borribooks.com/) in the railway station. It is on the side of the bus station on the Piazza dei Cinquecento. There are two floors, so go upstairs if you don't find the travel guides immediately on the ground floor. I think they are on the upper floor, but my memory might fail me on this.
The store is open from 7am to 10pm (8am to 10pm on Sundays).

If you click on "Orari d'apertura" on the website, you'll find a map with the location. Like @mts said in his comment, you can't miss it.